# Adding an asset to a release through GitHub action triggered on release creation

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, github-cli

We have a GitHub Actions workflow triggered by the creation of a release, i.e.,

```
on:
  release:
    types: [created]
```

How can we add the built files to the triggereing release as an asset from within the workflow?

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65676491/8028981) recommending `softprops/action-gh-release`, but that seems to apply to workflows triggered by pushes (with tags) and not "on release".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same action with the `on: release` trigger.

The GITHUB_REF environment variable or GitHub.ref context variable should contain the tag of the release.

See:

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#release

Another way to add files to the workflow is to use the GitHub CLI:

```
gh release upload $GITHUB_REF path/to/file path/to/file etc
```

That way you don't need to pull in actions from the marketplace.

```
${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}
```

Is another way to access the tag name.

Comment: Can `path/to/file` be a directory or do I have to create a zip first?

Comment: It can contain wildcards. But simplest thing you can do to see how this behaves it to create a quick workflow and test the scenario.